# Statement about the Killing vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry

I was reading "Tensor Analysis and Elementary Differential Geometry for Physicists and Engineers" by Hung Nguyen-Schäfer and Jan-Philip Schmidt and in the chapter 3 named "Differential geometry".

They introduce the Killing vector field $K$

> The Killing vector field K is defined as a vector field in an N-dimensional manifold in which the Lie derivative of the metric tensor g with respect to the vector field K along the congruence equals zero.

Or in a more mathematical writing, with $L$ the Lie derivative, they present it as:

> $L_K g=0$

Then, they try an example with the spherical coordinates:

> As an example of the Killing vector field, the covariant metric coefficients of the spherical coordinates $(r,\varphi, \theta)$ are given in:
>   $$g_{rr} = 1$$
>   $$g_{\varphi \varphi} = r^2$$
>   $$g_{\theta \theta} = r^2 \sin^2 \varphi$$

Which is just the norm of $g_{i}$ : $g_{ii} = g_{i} \cdot g_{i}$

(Reminder that $g$ is the metric tensor)

Then, they state the following statement:

> Equation (3.156) shoys that the metric coefficients are independant of the coordinates $(r,\varphi, \theta)$. Hence, the basis vectors $g_{r}$, $g_{\varphi}$ and $g_{\theta}$ are the Killing vectors.

However, I am really confused about this statement. For me, $g_{\theta \theta}$ is a function of both $r$ and $\varphi$ and $g_{\varphi \varphi}$ is a function of $r$. Therefore this statement doesn't seem true. Can someone explain it to me why I am wrong or what I misunderstood? Or is it a typo?

Comment: Where is equation $(3.156)$?

Comment: And wouldn't the basis vectors be $\frac {\partial} {\partial{r}},\frac {\partial} {\partial{\phi}},$ and $\frac {\partial} {\partial \theta}? $